# Adding labels and colored lines to a subset of square grid

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, graphs

I am aware of how one would generate a square grid on latex, but I was wondering if there would be a way of drawing this set with the given labels ($R_1$, $N$ and $R_2$) in the image? I would also like to see if there would be a way to draw the green and blue lines seen in this picture.

[image]

I am able to generate the dots required for the graph as

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip (-1,-1) rectangle (6cm,6cm); 
    

    \foreach \x in {1,2,3,4}
    {
        \foreach \y in {0,1,2}
        {
            \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill] at (.5*\x,.5*\y) {};
        }
    }
    \foreach \x in {0,5}{
    \foreach \y in {1}{
     \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill] at (.5*\x,.5*\y) {};
    }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But I am struggling to add the blue and green lines as well as the labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give each node a name using `\node(name)[...] {label}` and draw the lines and add the labels.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \x in {1,...,4}{
            \foreach \y in {0,...,2}{
                \node(circ-\x-\y)[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill] at (.5*\x,.5*\y) {};
            }
        }
        \foreach \x in {0,5}{
            \foreach \y in {1}{
                \node(circ-\x-\y)[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill] at (.5*\x,.5*\y) {};
            }
        }
        
        % lines
        
        \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using int(\i+1)] in {2,...,4}{
            \draw[green!50!black] (circ-1-0) -- (circ-\i-2);
            \draw[blue!50!black] (circ-1-0) -- (circ-\j-1);
        }

        % labels
        
        \node[right] at ($(circ-5-1) - (0,0.5)$) {$\mathrm{R_2}$};
        \node[right] at (circ-5-1) {$\mathrm{N}$};
        \node[right] at ($(circ-5-1) + (0,0.5)$) {$\mathrm{R_1}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```